# laravel5 migration copy existing table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, migration

I have table "table_1" which was formulated by many migrations (add/change fields)

I want to create new table which is copy of existing one "copy_of_table_1" (using migrations) with the same structure as "table_1" what is the best way to do this ?

I want to avoid make new migration and copy paste all added changed fields

Answer (score 20):

You can do this with a raw query:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class MyNewTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        DB::statement('CREATE TABLE newtable LIKE oldtable; ');
    }


    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('newtable');
    }

}
```

Definitely not recommended, but possible.

Comment: What are the disadvantages of this method?

Comment: Why "Definitely not recommended" if that's what a migration needs to do?

Comment: Mainly because you're using a SQL statement here instead of Laravel, so it's a lot less understandable at a glance. There could also be potential issues with migration failures and re-runs.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to create new migration and add fields from all add/change migrations. I don't see any smarter solution here.

Comment: I want to avoid make new migration and copy paste all fields (there are more than 20 migration)

Comment: Well, you asked for the best way. ) All other ways to do that are worse. Look, you still need to create a migration (as you said, you want to use migrations). If you do not want to use migrations, you could copy `CREATE` clause from existing table, change table name and run the clause.